# Which was the comic where Superman destroyed an entire solar system just by sneezing?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, episode-identification

There was a comic where Superman went in some other dimension and sneezed so hard that he destroyed an entire solar system ?

Comment: Gotta be Silver Age with the power of Super Sneezing.

Comment: I can't find the issue number right now, but discussion about that sneeze can be found here: https://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/gen-discussion-1/superman-the-sneeze-1845359/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[Action Comics Vol 1 273](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_273)**

From the synposis:

> Superman is once more plagued by Mr. Mxyzptlk's foolish pranks and practical jokes. **After making the Man of Steel destroy a distant Solar System with a super-sneeze**, and changing the moon into cheese.

And the moment in question:

[image: Superman destroying a solar system]

Comment: Superman went to a universe where all life vanished due to a terrible space-plague, and then started sneezing. I’d be worried. Then again, I’m not Superman.